# sum array inside for loop and call it outside of function

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Im trying to sum an array that has been populated by a loop, but i can only call the last value in the array.

def nots():

```
global smhx

tilt, lfo = genfromtxt('reso.csv',
        unpack=True, 
        delimiter=',')


for t in xrange(2,5200):

        mrt=max(tilt[0:t])

        x= 1-((lfo[t-1]-lfo[0])/(mrt-lfo[0]))

        results=np.array([x])

        smhx=np.sum(results)



    print smhx/5200
```

Without saving the array to another file and then calling it outside the function, can someone suggest the proper method?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but I am answering what was asked in the title:

To call a value outside of a function, use `global`, or pass it in as a parameter:

Using `global`:

```
>>> global var
>>> var = 8
>>> def foo():
...     global var
...     var+=1
... 
>>> var
8
>>> foo()
>>> foo()
>>> var
10
```

Passing it in:

```
>>> var = 8
>>> def foo(var):
...     var+=1
...     return var
...
>>> var
8
>>> for k in range(3):
...     var = foo(var)
...
>>> var
11
```

In your code, everything is fine; you are set up to use `global`. To call that variable from another function, just call:

```
def foo():
    global smhx
    #Do whatever you want with smhx
    smhx+=500
```

Comment: smhx becomes just one value. That value is the last value in the array of 5200 records, rather than the sum of them. I understand the global variable, but i don't understand why i am only getting the last value in the array, rather than the sum of 5200 records.

Comment: Now when i try to write it to a CSV, its writing it in Chinese?